# How to join one row to every row in source table using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following table (table A):

```
ID | Data  |
1  | Data1 |
2  | Data2 |
3  | Data3 |
4  | Data4 |
```

I have table B that has *1 row*:

```
DummyID | Dummy  |
1       | Dummy1 |
```

I have to join table A with table B in the following way:

```
ID | Data  |DummyID | Dummy  |
1  | Data1 |1       | Dummy1 |
2  | Data2 |1       | Dummy1 |
3  | Data3 |1       | Dummy1 |
4  | Data4 |1       | Dummy1 |
```

Obviously I can't use any ID in the `on` clause.

```
from item in context.TableA
join dummy in context.TableB on ? = ?
select new 
 {
  RowA=item,
  Dummy=dummy
 }
```

How could I do that with LINQ?

Comment: You don't need the join. Simply use another 'from':
from item in context.TableA
from dummy in context.TableB
select new {...}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a cross join which you can get via Linq in the following way

```
from item in context.TableA
from dummy in context.TableB
select new 
 {
  RowA=item,
  Dummy=dummy
 }
```

Or the following in method syntax

```
context.TableA.SelectMany(
    item => context.TableB.Select(dummy => new { RowA = item, Dummy = dummy }));
```

Note that if TableB every has more than one row you'll end up with N times M rows where N is the number of rows in TableA and M is the number of rows in TableB.

Comment: Yes, indeed. That is what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No need to join at all.

```
from item in context.TableA
select new 
{
    RowA = item,
    Dummy = context.TableB.FirstOrDefault()
}
```

Having said that, I'd have to question why you're doing this. The idea of LINQ is to get your relational data into an object-oriented form. Why not just retrieve the `TableB` information once and do whatever processing you need to do in-memory? It would reduce the size of the payload you're transferring from the database back to the application.

Comment: if tableB always has one row, adding `context.TableB.First()` will do the trick

Comment: @dbarnes: Oops, forgot the `FirstOrDefault`. I actually tried this against one of my databases and `First` gave an error but `FirstOrDefault` worked. I meant to add it but made an error when transferring from LINQPad to my response. Fixed it now.

Comment: @CraigW. I do some extra work with the dummy data, I just left it out to simplify the question.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use join. You want to use each item in your old sequence to create a different item in your new sequence. In LINQ you would use Enumerable.Select for this:

```
var dummy = context.Dummy.FirstOrDefault();
var newSequence = context.TableA
    .Select(itemInTableA =>
        new
        {
            RowA = itemInTableA,
            Dummy = dummy,
        });
```

Comment: The problem here is that you are now running two SQL queries instead of one.  Though if TableB only has only one row it's probably not a big deal.

Comment: I wrote this to make it easier to understand. Of course you could write Dummy = Dummy.FirstOrDefault(),